# Execute function with semicolon in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, compilation

I have two functions:

```js
const functionA = function() {
   return 30;
}

const functionB = function(num) {
   return num*2;
}

const c = functionB(functionA());
```

I know it is very straightforward the way it is, but why can't we write the code like this:

```js
const c = functionB(functionA(););    // with an semicolon in the inner braces
```

Doesn't that inner functionA get executed too?

I have another function:

```js
const functionAnother = function() {
   //does nothing
}
```

We know that it is illegal to have an empty line of execution just like:

```
;
```

but we can write code like:

```
functionAnother();
```

and since functionAnother returns nothing, isn't it just like this:

```
;
```

Comment: ; is end of statement, `functionB(functionA(););` should be similar to `functionB(functionA();` and `);`

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon doesn't have anything to do with execution, it just marks the end of the statement. Parens `()` are really the thing that invoke the execution.

so, `const c = functionB(functionA(););` throws an error because JS thinks you're starting a new line with nothing but `);` on it after the first semicolon (and the statement on the line before it is incomplete/invalid syntax).

However, if you remove that semicolon...

`const c = functionB(functionA());`

...you have something perfectly valid (and common). This will execute `functionA` first, and pass its return value as a parameter to `functionB`.

Does this help your understanding?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the result of `functionA()` into `functionB`, you are treating the result of `functionA()` as an expression. Because it is an expression (something that has a value, in this case, 30) and not a statement (an instruction to do something), you would not put a semicolon after it. Does that make sense?

I'm not certain what your second question is asking. If you're trying to have an empty line of code, you can make one by not writing anything on that line. I believe that `;` is actually a legal JavaScript statement, going by this page: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch06_19.htm

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

Semicolons are used at the end of statements. A statement can be thought of as an action or instruction which will be performed/carried out by the program. The semi-colon marks the end of this instruction. Thus, when you use a semi-colon in the middle of a statement (ie when it isn't finished) your technically ending your instruction early, and thus you'll get a syntax error:

```js
function functionA() {};
function functionB() {};
const c = functionB(functionA(););
```

To answer your second question:

When a function doesn't return anything it is actually implicitly returning undefined:

```js
function functionA() {

}

console.log(functionA());
```

And so instead of having:

```
;
```

By itself, you have something like so:

```js
console.log("foo");
undefined;
console.log("bar");
```